# Posting String parameter while uploading audio (Android)

Tags: android, file, file-upload, http-post

I am using following class to upload audio, and its working well. But i want to post one string along with audio file . So please tell me how to do thanks

Uploading class :

```
// open a URL connection to the Servlet
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

// Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

    //Need to upload this with audio 
conn.setRequestProperty("insert_id" , RowId);
conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```